# Experiences with adding Nonces to the comment form

Tags: plugins, themes, comments, spam

I was wondering about the impact nonces would have on the default comment form a theme has. Because [Nonces are a built-in feature of WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field) I thought about giving it a try.

***Does somebody has already implemented nonces in the standard comment form?*** (can't imagine that I'm the first one who thinks about that... !)

Can someone suggest an already existing plugin that does the job or provide a code snippet that integrates the WP Nonce Field into the themes comment form and checks for it when the form gets submitted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't done this personally, but it would be pretty easy. If you are building your comment form manually, just before the end of the `</form>` put:

`<?php wp_nonce_field( 'comment_nonce' ) ?>`

Then, just hook into the `pre_comment_on_post` action which fires when you submit a comment:

```
add_action( 'pre_comment_on_post', 'my_verify_comment_nonce' );

function my_verify_comment_nonce() {

    check_admin_referer( 'comment_nonce' );

}
```

If you want to just hook into the standard comment form that Twenty Ten uses (`comment_form()`) then you could instead hook into `comment_form` like so:

```
add_action( 'comment_form', 'my_add_comment_nonce_to_form' );

function my_add_comment_nonce_to_form() {

    wp_nonce_field( 'comment_nonce' );

}
```

Not tested, so let me know if you have any issues!

Comment: Oh I'll give it a try and then provide a core patch if it seems fit. Should prevent the one-request-spammers from entering comments any longer. check_admin_referer() might be misused, because it ain't the admin - or is it? Need to look into how comments are stored.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no problem with using `check_admin_referer()`, I think the name is a little misleading.

Comment: I'll rate this as answered or the moment because it mostly seems fit. Thanks for sharing!